# Take only right word a field column in Teradata

Tags: teradata, trim

I want to have only the right word of a string like this in Teradata?

```
Tim Tom Dave
```

How to trim Tim and Tom and only get Dave?

```
substring(ABC, Index(ABC, ' ') -1)
```

This is always from left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`instr` allows to search backwards:

```
substr(ABC, instr(ABC, ' ', -1)+1)
```

`-1` = last occurance

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp_substr:

`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Tim Tom Dave', '[^\s]+$')`

The '$' tells us to search backwards from the end of the string.
`[^\s]` tells us to match any character that isn't a space.